# Setting color during edit

Tags: discussion

I haven't found any similar question.
**Why colouring of text is disabled? Wouldn't this be especially useful during edits?**
It would reduce need of copying blocks of code to show differences made during editing of question by yourself.

Note: I'm not talking about automatic syntax colouring. I imagine this could be text purposely marked as red/blue, by owner, inside existing question.

Note2: Not talking about viewing "edit" diffs too, because when anyone visits question for the first time, usually view's just question, not edited versions too.

EDIT: some additional clarification below.

When You enter link, You see above text, and sentence starting with word EDIT. I had to manually enter "EDIT" to make it obvious for anyone NOT browsing "edited" button showing revisions below, what I have changed. My idea was that during editing, OP would be able to color some parts of own answer/question, to make it instantly visible what was changed during edit (something like bold attribute). Those edits would be still visible in history revisions.

Comment: Wait.  Are you talking about the colors in an edit diff?

Comment: no. I'm talking about inline color in question (regardless of set syntax). Imagine huge block of text, where You want to edit some stuff, but in visible way to make it clear that that was added after edit.

Comment: Isn't that *precisely* what the edit diff is for?  It's a lighter shade of red and green, but coloring of the diff exists that isn't obtrusive to the overall edit or post.

Comment: Yes, but rarely/hardly ever when You find a question/answer You check edits. Inline colours would enable to show process: "THIS was my question" and i have changed "THIS was my question. -color- BUT i have changed that to make it work better etc -color end-"

Comment: I think that would be incredibly distracting. Just look at the giant red and green blocks you can get in the edit history after making even minor changes.

Comment: Are you saying you want the highlighting of edits to be visible *while* you're editing?

Comment: True, so my idea was that this would be optional and possible to be used only by OP. Maybe even with some rep requirement? Yet it seems You don't find it useful, so perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: _"I had to manually enter "EDIT""_ No, you didn't. Actually, you actively added what we here consider noise to your post. When you edit a question, you should make it flow as if the added information had been there all along. If someone wishes to see what it looked like previously, or what you added, then they can click "edited" and look for that information. For everyone else, it's just in the way of what they're there for: The information in your post. In my mind, these "colors" would not only be the same, but would likely be misused by new users to make their post "pretty" or for emphasis.

Comment: If a question needs improvement, improve it. Leave a coherent question that would make just as much sense to someone who never read the earlier versions.  If the edit was in response to a comment or an answer, leave a comment in the appropriate place telling *those who would want to know* that an edit was made. No one who finds the question later would care about the history.

Comment: @Kendra i disagree. Well, partially. Surely, it might be misused, as many different things. That's not my concern here, cause there are a lot of questions lacking **content**, so style would be least of my concern. Yet, for You this might be noise, but some might find it useful to show changes for example answering, or improving own question. And Paul - it doesn't need to mean that it was wrong, but it might carry additional information. And again, I want to stress that IMHO this would reduce duplicating HUGE blocks of code of Q/A where several lines are altered.

Comment: @JustMe not for her only. Stack is against anything "meta" in the post. And adding "I EDITED THIS IN THIS QUESTION" is definitely meta, so noise by Stack's definition. I'm not saying sometimes it isn't helpful. Click on "edit" if you want to see it. Anyway how would your system account for changes in code that is already highlighted? It sounds like it'll be distracting and confusing....

Comment: I agree that this could easily be useful for _some_ users. You know what else could be? A private messaging system. But it's highly unlikely that will ever be added because it would cause more harm than good to the site. As for _"this would reduce duplicating HUGE blocks of code of Q/A where several lines are altered."_ If your code blocks are that long, you should consider making sure you can't narrow them down into a better MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) to help answerers better answer your questions.

Comment: If the goal is to have questions/code that fit in 3 lines of text, sure You're right. But what about any question that is longer and does not touch simple Q/A that could be answered easily? And BTW how do You search for those? There are a lot of questions that show effort, but since people just grind for reputation points they often skip questions that require work to answer. And long questions are difficult to answer that long will SO attract low level of short questions, cause hard problems won't get solved.

Comment: @Patrice: "how would your system account for changes in code that is already highlighted" - just boolean, say, OP wants this marked as edited it overrides any syntax highlight. OP makes another edit - it is treated as normal part of Q/A.

Comment: @JustMe so, because you want your edit to show more, syntax highlighting has to break? no. Just no

Comment: Break for single line, just line...well ok, let's say it ;) "meta comment"

Comment: @JustMe but why break what looks like perfectly fine code because you want an edit to show more. That's the part I don't get. A question should be 100% complete and there is no benefit to seeing what was changed. So breaking syntax highlighting (even for a character) is not acceptable, when the gain isn't actually something that we find helpful or relevant..

Comment: @Patrice Well, this is surely good point, yet take a look what modern code review tools are doing? Allowing inline commenting. I guess I was imagining something of such sort.

Comment: @justme but what's the benefit? For a feature to be done, there needs to be added value. your feature siunds awfully complicated, confusing and noise-inducing... for a benefit you've not made clear yet....

Comment: @Patrice, I think that meta is a place for discussing ideas, so this was mine - allowing inline comments like modern code review tools do. I think it is beneficial in such way that mistakes are best commented in place of existence, not hundred lines below. Just my opinion, as I said - since this gets down-voted, apparently people do not consider that code review function useful here on SO, which is fine. I couldn't say if there is more to it for anyone else, for me this is benefit.

Comment: *"this would reduce duplicating HUGE blocks of code of Q/A where several lines are altered."* - I'm still really confused by this. How does highlighting text prevent you from duplicating anything? Why is anything being duplicated in a question in the first place?

Comment: @BSMP say You wrote a Java class GUI, MCVE, and it's 20 lines long. Now, to show Your question better You might have had written 30, but this contradicts MCVE. You might insert inline comment to that. Second part - about duplication, say You have a Q, and answer requires posting code change, You might of course pinpoint exact location in OP's post, but since there are no line numbers, it is sometimes easier to copy and paste whole class with several small changes made.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is really no need for that kind of noise.

We don't care about how the post reached it's current level of quality. The most important usage goal of any SE site is to provide searchable questions with quality answers at any moment in time.

It shouldn't matter if I have seen all revisions of the posts or just the latest. I should be able to fully grasp what is being asked or what the answer tries to explain to me. If I'm interested I visit the revision history of the post.

The noise reduction is a key-value in the success rate of the site. Feeling the need to introduce meta-noise like **EDIT** and *better idea*, <s>or bad idea</s> should be a signal for you. Your post needs a re-write. Don't expect your readers to scrape the pieces together to create a coherent post.

Answer (score 8):

I see a couple problems with this idea, which is likely why it wasn't ever, and probably isn't going to be, implemented.

Let's start with what edits should be, since you feel this would be useful for edits. Edits should improve a post's formatting and clarity. Edits should not add unnecessary information or noise to a post, to help keep a post clear and easy to read. In the case of questions, this can help to getting better, faster answers.

Taking this into consideration, here are why I feel this is a bad idea:

#### 1. This would be noise.

When you edit to add information, make your question more clear, show more examples of what you've done, etc. you should edit your post in a way that anyone coming late to the party would feel like the question had been that way all along. Your post should flow as if it had never been edited, even if it has undergone several revisions. Users who wish to see what has changed since the post was created can do this by clicking "edited x ago" and checking the revision history.

For most users, however, this information won't be necessary. Therefore, if you give them the unnecessary information, either with this color idea or with "EDIT" and "UPDATE" blocks, you put noise in the way of the information they are after. Often times, these blocks do not flow well with the previous information, meaning the reader will need to take longer to parse and understand all the information.

Even in answers, this kind of color difference would be unnecessary. If an answer changes the code from the question, it's in the answerer's best interest (as in, they are more likely to have a well-received answer) if they *explain* what changes they made and why they made them. If they don't, they leave the door open for an answer that does, and more often than not, the answer that gives the explanation will get more recognition than the answer that doesn't.

For this reason, I feel that this color difference would be noise. While it would highlight the differences, as you point out, it would also get in the way of the users who don't *care* what the changes you've made are. We don't want to get in the way of getting information to other users, especially when we want them to answer our questions.

#### 2. This would be misused.

Even if we implemented this only for the OP, as you suggest in the comments of your question, this would be misused. Even with a minimum rep requirement, such as say 15 rep, it's highly likely that newer users would use this either to make their post "pretty" or to emphasis information that does not need to be emphasized.

Now, on it's own, I don't feel like this would be a *major* reason to disregard this feature. After all, several formatting options, for instance **bold** and `inline code` are misused all the time by new users, yet we still allow both. But added to the fact that this would likely be more noise than anything, I feel that this might not be the best idea to implement.

---

I can see how it could be useful to some users, but I feel like this would be unnecessary noise for more than it would help. After all, if a user comes to your post, they usually won't care what the past revisions looked like, or what has changed on it. It's far more likely they'll only care what the post currently looks like and currently tells them, and they'll care that the information is conveyed in an easy to read and parse way.

If your questions tend to have such long code blocks that you feel you *need* this to help make adding new things you've tried easier to show, to reduce copy/paste/edit for the long code blocks or to help shorten the length of the question by not having to put the *entire* code block again with the changes, consider making sure you can't trim your code down a bit more and remove anything not completely necessary to the question. There's a good chance you don't have [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help answerers more easily help you solve the issue.

Comment: Most Java Q/A have long code blocks, especially regarding packages, having many imports and so on so on. How do You propose asking question about packages, and creating MCVE of GUI in Swing? And how many lines is "too many"? And surely, trimming to "minimal" is good idea, unless You have TWO or more questions, as it is encouraged to have separate Q for each. And You would need to post nearly same code in other Q.

Comment: "Too many" is subjective, which is why I specified _"that you feel you need this help"_ in the answer. Note that I said "good chance," not that it's guaranteed that this would mean you have too much code. It depends on the language, the question, etc. As for _"unless You have TWO or more questions"_ the questions should each stand on their own. If you wish to link between them to show they are related, that's fine, but if code in one is not necessary to find the issue in the other, then that question does not need all the code from the other.

Comment: And concerning _"How do You propose..."_ if I don't work with the languages, I can't easily tell you what's acceptable in each. I'm giving only general guidelines and suggestions in order to aid you in your future ventures to find answers. If I could give you advice on _every_ language and framework, I would likely have far more rep than I do. :)

Comment: @JustMe let me add that I get the feeling from both your question and comments that you are trying to solve an issue from the wrong end. Posts that are so complex that they need a reading guide (with color or meta-noise) simply aren't good posts for us. Those posts need to be edited but even better down voted and closed. Your suggestion might give the impression to the low-quality posters that it is OK to post crap because they can fix it with coloring and stuff like that. Make no mistake: we hate low quality here.

Comment: @rene, please, make no mistake that I use SO from whence this account was created. I actually cannot decide whether You are joking about "hating low quality", or is it just me viewing different questions happening to be constantly added that would get classified so, even being quite tolerant.

Comment: Maybe *hating low quality* is somewhat exaggerated but I see enough stuff, either live or in the queues that needs severe editing, closing and deleting. Those posts will not improve by having your bells and whistles added. The contrary I would say. It might make them easier to spot so I know where to spend my votes....